# Datatables and sum column with discount and original price in the same cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'd like (in datatables) to sum column to get total in footer, but in my case I've to show original price and discount price inside same cell:

```
<td data-price="100"><p style="text-decoration:line-through;color:red;"><small>150</small></p>100</td>
```

I'm using now this:

```
"footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
    var api = this.api(),
    intVal = function (i) {
          return typeof i === 'string' ?
               i.replace(/[, Rs]|(\.\d{2})/g,"")* 1 :
               typeof i === 'number' ?
               i : 0;
    },
    total2 = api
        .column(2)
        .data()
        .reduce(function (a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        }, 0);

     $(api.column(2).footer()).html(
        total2
     );
}
```

It work great for standard cells like: `<td>200</td>` but if I've this:

```
<td data-price="100"><p style="text-decoration:line-through;color:red;"><small>150</small></p>100</td>
```

I don't know how to fix it.

My fiddle: http://live.datatables.net/sadipaji/610/edit

Answer (score 0):

https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum()
This is the link for the plugin, you need to use to strip off all the character except the integer column value.

There are two ways you can register this plugin
1. Just add the plugin link
2. Use the plugin code directly in your js file

> jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'sum()'String, function ( ) {

```
return this.flatten().reduce( function ( a, b ) {

    if ( typeof a === 'string'String ) {

        a = a.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''String) * 1;

    }

    if ( typeof b === 'string'String ) {

        b = b.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''String) * 1;

    }



    return a + b;

}, 0 );
```

} );